# Does a one-dimensional array have a direction?

Tags: arrays, dimensions

Well, the title says it. Does a one-dimensional array have a direction? Or is the direction of a one dimensional array undefined?

Or maybe stated differently: when visualizing a one-dimensional array, should you visualize it top-down or left-right? Or is this arbitrary?

Does it depend on the programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on if it's key value pair it could or it couldn't have a direction.  If you assign an array like this

```
a[0]='something'
a[1]='something else'
a[2]='something something else'
```

Then it definitely looks like it has a direction.  Versus something like this

```
a['foo']='bar'
a[5]='five'
a['a']=1
```

If you're talking about how the array is actually stored in memory then that's a different story.  I can't remember exactly from my CS classes but I'm pretty sure that the data in an array is stored randomly and just terminated with a pointer to the next part of the array.  Don't quote me on that though.

Comment: You suggest the first example implicates a direction. What direction would that be in your opinion? Because to me that doesn't seem so trivial.

The second suggestion shows another perspective to the problem, very useful. That would implicate a one dimensional array has no direction right? There would not really be a 'correct' way to print such an array.

Comment: Well you can still run foreach functions on the second array so it has to have some method of choosing when the elements are shown.  I'm pretty sure that that would just be where the array is stored in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like *is a 1D array a row-vector or a column-vector ?* then the answer is *it depends*.

Matlab, for example, recognises that a `1 x m` vector is not the same as an `m x 1` vector.

Fortran, on the other hand, does not recognise the distinction.

I'm sure other languages have their own conventions too.

As for mathematics, the usual convention (in the areas I am familiar with) is that vectors are column-vectors.

Take your pick.

Comment: But wouldn't a `1 x m` vector not be a two-dimensional array? It has two dimensions right? Only one of the two happens to be one.